# How to authenticate with GitHub using Pulumi Flux package in Go

Tags: go, kubernetes, github, pulumi, fluxcd

I want to bootstrap FluxCD on Kubernetes through a Pulumi inline program written in Go but am unable to give it access to GitHub.

As seen in the code below, I first create a new Pulumi provider then pass it to `flux.NewFluxBootStrapGit` just like the docs ([`flux.NewProvider`](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/flux/api-docs/provider/), [providers](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/concepts/resources/providers/)) suggest to do.

```golang
package fluxCdTest

import (
    "github.com/oun/pulumi-flux/sdk/go/flux"
    "github.com/pulumi/pulumi/sdk/v3/go/pulumi"
)


func CreateNewProvider(ctx *pulumi.Context, kubeconfigPath string) (*flux.Provider, error) {
    provider, err := flux.NewProvider(ctx, "flux", &flux.ProviderArgs{
        Git: &flux.ProviderGitArgs{
            
            // I tried HTTP first
            // Url:    pulumi.String("https://github.com/org_name/fluxcd-test"),
            // Http: &flux.ProviderGitHttpArgs{
            //  AllowInsecureHttp: pulumi.Bool(false),
            //  Password:          pulumi.String("..."),
            //  Username:          pulumi.String("my_github_username"),
            // },

            Branch: pulumi.String("main"),

            Url: pulumi.String("ssh://git@github.com/org_name/fluxcd-test"),
            Ssh: &flux.ProviderGitSshArgs{
                PrivateKey: pulumi.String(`
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----`),
                Username: pulumi.String("my_github_username"),
            },
        },
        Kubernetes: &flux.ProviderKubernetesArgs{
            ConfigPath: pulumi.String(kubeconfigPath),
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return provider, nil
}

func BootStrapFlux(ctx *pulumi.Context, provider *flux.Provider, repoDirPath string) error {

    _, err := flux.NewFluxBootstrapGit(ctx, "this", &flux.FluxBootstrapGitArgs{
        Path: pulumi.String(repoDirPath),
    }, pulumi.Provider(provider))

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil

}
```

I tried using `Http` first. It couldn't authenticate, so I tried `Ssh` but it says:

```bash
flux:index:FluxBootstrapGit (this):

error: Git Client: could not clone git repository: unable to clone 'ssh://my_github_username@github.com/org_name/fluxcd-test': ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
```

For SSH, I followed GitHub's instructions to create [deploy keys](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/managing-deploy-keys#deploy-keys). I added the public key to the repo and the private key to the code above.

The code above is run like this:

```golang
    ctx := context.Background()
    stackName := "test-stack"
    projectName := ...
    var opts = ...

    kubeconfigPath := "/Users/my_username/.kube/config"

    deployFunc := func(ctx *pulumi.Context) error {
        provider, _ := CreateNewProvider(ctx, kubeconfigPath)

        _ = BootStrapFlux(ctx, provider, "clusters/my-cluster")

        return nil
    }

    stack, _ := auto.UpsertStackInlineSource(ctx, stackName, projectName, deployFunc, opts...)

    res, _ := stack.Up(ctx)
```

I read through the [FluxCD docs](https://fluxcd.io/flux/installation/bootstrap/github/) as well but the Pulumi Flux package has fewer options. E.g., I don't see a field for a Personal Access Token.

I'm quite new to this. What am I missing?

Comment: When authenticating to github using ssh, the username is always `git`. You don't use your actual username.

Answer (score 1):

jordanm in the comment is totally right. Username when using SSH to authenticate with GitHub is always `git`, not our actual usernames.

So this works:

```golang
Ssh: &flux.ProviderGitSshArgs{
    ...
    Username: pulumi.String("git"),
},
```

I haven't learnt why I can't authenticate with Http but in the interest of time I'll go with what works for now.

Comment: Authenticating with HTTP you have use your username and a PAT (personal access token).